# Difference in python quantile (numpy, statistics)

Tags: python, numpy, function, statistics, quantile

today I made my own function to solve quantile/decile/percentile:

```
from math import floor, ceil
def mean(x: list)->float:
""""arithmetic mean (average) of list
adding all elements and divide by umber of elements"""
if len(x) < 1:
    raise TypeError("mean need at least one element")
else:
    sum_of_elements =sum(x)
    mean_value = sum_of_elements/len(x)
    return mean_value

def percentiles(percentile, x:list)->float:
'''Percentile is the value below which the values of a given percentage of samples fall.
percentile = 25, 50, 75,100 is 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quartile
percentile = 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 is 1st, 2nd, 3rd
4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th and 10th decile.'''
x = sorted(x)
n = len(x)
if percentile <1 or percentile >100:
    raise TypeError("percentile should be in range 1-100")
if n<0:
    raise TypeError("list cannot be empty")
location = percentile*(n+1)/100
if int(location) == location:
    return x[int(location)-1]
else:
    down = floor(location)
    up = ceil(location)
    if down == 0:
        return x[up]
    else:
        even = mean([x[down-1], x[up-1]])
        return even
```

When I compare this function above with np.quantile and statistics.quantiles I get different results. For example list:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,21]
my q1: 3.5
statistics q1: 3.75 (with method = 'exclusive') or 4.25 (with method = 'inclusive')
Numpy q1: 4.25 (?)

What's wrong with my percentiles() function? When I do it on paper I always get results the same as percentiles().

Comment: did you read [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html)?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to use alpha and beta in my code. Somebody suggested me to change n+1 to n-1, but I think it is good solution.